# How to search all documents in given Index using search API?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, kibana, nest

I'm trying to get all the (2 doc) documents in the Index using NEST search API.

I created an Index "Masato" from console in Kibana and when I run the list of Index i can see it there.

GET /_cat/indices?v

[image]

The Index "Masato" contains two documents.

GET /masato/doc/_search?q=*

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "masato",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Foo Bar"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "masato",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "John Doe"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now.. I'm trying to use search API to obtain those info. (I have .NET Web API setup) Please note that I replaced actual URI to 'xxxxx'

```
namespace DockerTest.Controllers
{
    public class ElasticSearchController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetElasticSearch()
        {
            try
            {
                var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("xxxxx"))
                .EnableDebugMode();

                var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

                var searchResponse = client.Search<Masato>(s => 
                s.Index("masato")
                .Type("doc"));

                return Ok(searchResponse.DebugInformation);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return Ok(ex.Message + ":::::" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
```

When the code above gets executed searchResponse.DebugInformation is returned to the browser and it says 404 Not Found:

```
done Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /masato/doc/_search
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://xxxxx Took: 00:00:00.3458454
# ServerError: ServerError: -1Type:  Reason: "Not Found"
# OriginalException: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TReturn](RequestData requestData)
# Request:
{}
# Response:
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"}
```

I'm bit stuck at this stage, could anyone shed me some light please.
Thanks

Comment: Are you managing this elastic cluster yourself or on elastic cloud? Are you able to POST requests and get non-404s from other endpoints?

Comment: It's in the cloud. I'll check POST request part

Comment: I'm getting 404 on the POST as well. Does that mean the access is blocked somehow?

Comment: What version of NEST are you using, and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting? If you're running against Elastic Cloud, where are you adding credentials to access the cluster?

Comment: Tried the local elastic server (localhost:9200) and I was able to obtain the data so at this point, it is likely that I'm missing to provide the necessary credential and not having authentication to access the cluster.

NEST version is 5.5

Comment: And Elasticsearch version you are targeting? You can add credentials using `.BasicAuthentication("username", "password")` on `ConnectionSettings`